# Font-size в разных браузерах

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с таким примером:

HTML

```
<div>
  Подтверждение QRS - пароля
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
 border:1px solid grey;
 width:298px;
 height:70px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 70px;
 font-family: "Lato"
}
```

Этот же пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/poodRxN)

В chrome текст отображается в одну строку и помещается в блоке, в firefox разбивается на две строки. Как я понимаю, происходит это из за того что браузеры считают font-size по разному. Как адекватно побороть это поведение?

Comment: В разных браузерах разные отступы padding или margin, советую сбросить все отступы и проверить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроссбраузерный и кроссплатформенный размер шрифта (`font-size`) в процентах и относительных единицах (`em`)
*Решаем вопрос установки размера шрифта, обеспечивающем единообразное отображение во всех браузерах*

> Используем подход `%/em` -- проценты плюс относительные единицы
>
> Очевидно, установку размера шрифта в процентах полностью отвергать
>   нельзя. Это необходимо для того, чтобы учитывать пользовательские
>   установки браузера (если таковые отличаются от дефолтных). Однако
>   далее необходим полный переход на относительные единицы (`em`). Обычно я
>   поступаю следующим образом:
>
> Устанавливаю `font-size` для `body` в `62.5%`
>       Поскольку теперь `1em` становится равным `10px`, далее использую для `font-size` только относительные значения, например `1.2em`
>       Соответствие между `em` и `px` определяем по формуле `"1em = 10px"`
>
> Пример такого решения выглядит гораздо читабельнее:

```
body      { font-size:62.5%; }
#header   { font-size:.9em; }
#main     { font-size:1.1em; }
```

> Кроме всего прочего, достигается подход `pixel-perfect` и полная
>   кроссбраузерность в отображении `font-size`. И клиенты довольны и
>   верстальщики целы.

*Источник http://www.seditio.by/blog/html_and_css/accessible-cross-browser-pixel-perfect-font-size

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая рекомендация. Но если в mozilla сделать:
body { font-size:62.5%; } и font-size:2em; так же разбивает на две строки. Хотя в хроме все красиво.

Comment: )Пожалуйста - попробуйте немного поиграть с шириной контейнера, средней и удобоваримой для обеих браузеров - одинаковость не только от фонта зависит - по крайне мере, я именно так и делаю в подобных случаях - буквально пиксельная подгонка для оптимального компромиса обеих браузеров.

Comment: Так и пришлось сделать. Увеличил контейнер, и отцентрировал текст. Зазоры разные получились, но выглядит в целом нормально)

Comment: Хорошо, рад, что получилось у Вас!